# This is not how you drink it

Tags: relative-clauses

Regarding relative adverbial "How", "how" can replace "conjunction" and "adverbial phrase" in original sentences.

So my thought is as follows.

**This is not how you drink it.**

→ This is not the way and you drink it not in the way.

→ This is not the way how you drink it.

→ This is not how you drink it. (because "HOW" cannot be used together with "the way".

My understanding is correct?

Comment: If you mean "Is **This is not how you drink it** the correct version?" - yes, it is. The other two are wrong.

Comment: Hi I mean, when there are two sentences and there is duplicate one, it can be combined one sentence with using relative adverb how.

Comment: So if there are two sentences like this. This not the way and you drink it not in the way. 
I can combine two sentences to one sentence with using how like this. This not how drink it not in the way.

Comment: _You drink it not in the way_ is not correct English. You would have to say _This is not the way to drink it_ or _You don't drink it this/that way_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is not how you drink it.

Is the only correct option. You can also say:

> The way you drink it is wrong.

> You drink it incorrectly.